# Complex Alphabetising in Excel?

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, duplicates, alphabetical

This is the kind of list I'm working with:

[image]

Basically the end game is to be able to get the list into alphabetical order, removing the 0's and removing any duplicates. I'm sure there is a way to do this without having to do anything manually but struggling to think of the best way to go about it. Any help would be great, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time/ rare thing, you can simply use the "remove duplicates" function found under the Data Ribbon > Data Tools > Remove Duplicates. Then select the column and rightclick, and click Sort. For something like this, automation should only be used if it is a repetitive task where data consistently comes in same form. Otherwise, learning to quickly apply the manual Excel tools will make you quicker in the long-run.